# PHP sending email listing contents of cart using foreach statement

Tags: php, email, cart

I have a shopping cart on a PHP site, which all works beautifully, but I am trying to create a function that emails the contents of the cart to a specified address.

I have the nuts and bolts with the email working perfectly, but I'm struggling to get each item in the cart to show.

So far I have the code below. The problem is with me adding a foreach loop within the $email_body variable, but as this is how I display the cart, I assumed this would be the way to create an email. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

session_start();

//echo "<br />CART: " . $_SESSION["cart"] . "<br />";

require_once('Connections/ships.php');

// Include functions

require_once('inc/functions.inc.php');

$cart = $_SESSION["cart"]; 

$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

$arrCart = explode(",", $cart);



// Open db

mysql_select_db($database_ships, $ships);


// Grab first (and only) row from query

$row = mysql_fetch_array($cart_items);


//create the variables

$email_from = 'anemailaddress@gmail.com';//<== update the email address

$email_subject = "Ship Image Information Request";

$email_body = "You have received a request for Ship Information from:" . $visitor_email. "They would like information on the following ships" . 

"foreach ($arrCart as $cart_item) {


$sql = 'SELECT ship_id, ship_name, image FROM ship_infomation WHERE ship_id = $cart_item LIMIT 1;';

$cart_items = mysql_query($sql, $ships) or die(mysql_error()) $row['ship_name'];

}";

$to = "anemailaddress@gmail.com";//<== update the email address

$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.php');

?>
```

Comment: The line after the comment "// Grab first (and only) row from query" seems to be extraneous -- it attempts to fetch a row from a result set variable that doesn't exist, then does nothing with that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to execute that loop, PHP code, not put the words "foreach arrcart..." into the text of your mail. That's what you're doing by putting it inside the string.

```
//start creating the e-mail body string
$email_body = "You have received a request for Ship Information from: ";

//add to the email body string
$email_body .= $visitor_email . "\n\n";

//add to the email body string
$email_body .= "They would like information on the following ships:\n\n";

//begin a loop over the entries of $arrCart
foreach ($arrCart as $cart_item) {

    //the query to look up the cart item's name
    $sql = "SELECT ship_name FROM ship_infomation WHERE ship_id = $cart_item LIMIT 1";

    //run the database query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    //retrieve a row from the query result
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //add a new line to the string in $email_body with the name we just looked up
    $email_body .= $row['ship_name'] . "\n";

}
```

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for your time doing that. I seem to get an error now though (Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/elbowroo/public_html/ship_image/form-to-email.php on line 28) which appears to be the line $row = mysql_fetch_array($cart_items); - would you have any pointers to fix this? THanks for your time

Comment: Yes, delete that line. It does nothing; there is no variable `$cart_items` in your code so why are you fetching a row from it? I commented on it below your question above.